# What is Applicative Builder

Tags: scala, functional-programming, applicative

I am scala and functional newbie and trying to learn applicatives.

```
val o1 = Some(1)
val o2 = Some(2)
val o3 = Some(3)
val result = (o1 |@| o2 |@| o3) {_ + _ + _}
```

There is a very good read about Applicatives and Functors [here](https://hackernoon.com/functors-and-applicatives-b9af535b1440)

As per this blog,

> Operator |@| is the product operation

and

> combining your applicatives into a product by using |@| results in an
> ApplicativeBuilder which takes a function to perform on the product
> (since product + map is a very common use case)

I am finding it very difficult to understand above two statements from the blog.
Any example with code in scala to understand this will be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the key take away from the post, which should help reason about applicative functors is this sentence:

> Hey, so **you got your function wrapped into a bit of a context**, huh?
>   Not to worry, I know how to apply those kind of wrapped functions

Applicative provides a way of applying a function wrapped in a context over other wrapped values.

`|@|` and the underlying type `ApplicativeBuilder` are just scalazs way of constructing these applicatives via a DSL.

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> Whereas a `scalaz.Functor` allows application of a pure function to
>   a value in a context, an Applicative also allows application of a
>   **function in a context to a value in a context** (`ap`)

---

> Operator |@| is the product operation

By "product operation" the OP means that it is the operation which takes two values and wraps them inside the `ApplicativeBuilder`.

`|@|` is a method that when invoked, returns an instance of `ApplicativeBuilder`:

```
final def |@|[B](fb: F[B]) = new ApplicativeBuilder[F, A, B] {
  val a: F[A] = self
  val b: F[B] = fb
}
```

Where `F` is a first order kind which has an `Apply` instance defined:

```
implicit val F: Apply[F]
```

Where `Apply` is just an `Applicative` without the `point` method.

> combining your applicatives into a product by using |@| results in an
>   ApplicativeBuilder which takes a function to perform on the product
>   (since product + map is a very common use case)

If you we take your example and simplify it a bit for two `Option[Int]`s:

```
import scalaz.Scalaz._

val o1 = 1.some
val o2 = 1.some
val result: ApplicativeBuilder[Option, Int, Int] = o1 |@| o2
val finalRes: Option[Int] = result.apply(_ + _)
```

We:

1. Apply `|@|` to two instances an of `Option[Int]` and get back an `ApplicativeBuilder[Option, Int, Int]`. `Option` here is our `F`, which has an instance of `Apply`.
2. After getting back an instance of the builder, we invoke it's `apply` method. We provide it with a function of shape `Int -> Int` and it gives us back a `Option[Int]`, meaning we are still inside the context, but with the operation applied to our values.

Comment: This is a very nice explanation. Kindly provide an example having a method with arity 3.

Comment: Also, where is implicit val F: Apply[F] is used in this example.

Comment: @mogli It is required on the `ApplyOps` class: `final class ApplyOps[F[_],A] private[syntax](val self: F[A])(implicit val F: Apply[F])`